# How to check for a signed return-type?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Imagine I have a callable template-parameter "Fn fn". Now I want to check that its return-type is a *signed* scalar. How can I do that with C++20 concepts ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed

Comment: Callable with what?

Answer (score 5):

To check if it can be called and return something of a category, just call it and examine the expression. That's what concepts are after all, a tool to write regular C++ code into and examine some of its properties.

```
template<typename T>
concept signed_scalar = std::signed_integral<T> || std::floating_point<T>;

template<typename Fn, typename... Args>
concept signed_result = requires(Fn fn, Args... args) {
    { fn(args...) } -> signed_scalar;
};
```

That's the only generic way given that overloading is always possible in any C++ program, including on a functor's `operator()`.

You can also be fancy and use `std::invoke` in lieu of the bare function call expression, to handle more "invokable" types. But you did not give an indication that's a requirement.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong I was trying to write an answer myself and tested this and [It's not working](https://godbolt.org/z/WTebcPdP4)

Comment: @Mgetz - You did not specify the arguments. They are not deducible from anywhere, again not possible against overloading. https://godbolt.org/z/bEz1j9WxW

Comment: And finally working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/91rz9Ev4e)

Comment: @Mgetz - I deleted the `std::invocable` for a reason. It doesn't do what you think it does. Does nothing to be precise (or do you not wonder how a check for "inokability" with no augments passes for a function that must accepts one?)

Comment: Demo link updated, mostly I wanted the working demo because I've written constraints before and been frustrated by the syntax. Examples (particularly working ones!) are important.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica `singed_result` => `signed_result`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Personally I like my results on the well-done side, so Freudian slip?